# Get single record from Firestore using Vue.js

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I am trying to get a single record from a Firestore db where I am pulling the ID from the path but it doesn't seem to be working.

Can you see what I am doing wrong please,

If I run the following code

```
   created() {
     //fetch data from firestore
   let ref = db.collection('post').doc(this.$route.params.id)
    ref.get()
    .then(snapshot => {  //DocSnapshot
        console.log(snapshot.data)
          if (doc.exists) {
            // doesnt run
            console.log('test')
              let post = snapshot.data()
          } else {
              // snapshot.data() will be undefined in this case
              // also doesn't run
              console.log("No such document!");
          }  
    })
  },
```

I get the following in the console

```
function (options) {
        validateBetweenNumberOfArgs('DocumentSnapshot.data', arguments, 0, 1);
        options = validateSnapshotOptions('DocumentSnapshot.data', options);
        return !this._document
            ? undefined
            : this.convertObject(this._document.data, FieldValueOptions.fromSnapshotOptions(options, this._firestore._areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled()));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I get the following in the console"? Which console?

Comment: Sorry I mean if I console.log that's what I get returned

Comment: It is strange that the console.log prints some code like `function (options) {validateBetweenNumberOfArgs('DocumentSnapshot.data', arguments, 0, 1);....` Are you sure??

Comment: Certain, its definitely whats returned and I can't get my head round it either. nothing in the if statement seems to be running at all as I get nothing returned in the console.log at all from either the if or else... Also my getall works absolutely fine from the created method... very strange. as far as I can make out its the ref.get() that seems to be my problem but I'm sure it should work?

Comment: This console.log result is what was printed when you tried the code provided in my answer below?

Comment: Yes, I used exactly what you shared, well with the console.logs as above

Comment: So it should come from another part of the code, because in the code below there is only one console.log: `console.log("No such document!");`!!

Comment: I added a console.log(snapshot.data), the code above is my exact code

Comment: I tried a console.log('success') in the if statement to but that didn't return anything

Comment: What happens if you put this code as a method (that you trigger e.g. by a button) and not in the `created()` hook.

Comment: Just tried in Firefox and get Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fitask-f5c26%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=myD79yqoR12h2aYYHPg1vqCIwGUsmoJ7&VER=8&RID=rpc&SID=F9Nhn-yCFRF-nKYLVC3cMw&CI=0&AID=5&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=6eelcthv7gvm&t=2. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). so assuming thats my issue but didn't think I would get that sort of issue from my localhost to firestorm?

Comment: Firestore not firestorm ;-)). You should not get this kind of CORS issue with the JavaScript SDK. Try as a simple method in your component

Comment: Sorry, yes firestore

Comment: Still not working for me even if I remove the if (doc.exists), I get undefined for the snapshot.data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177188/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-paul).

Comment: I realised that doc is undefined so if I use if(snapshot.exists) instead it works fine, thanks for the help as got me there in the end...just me being foolish

Comment: Happy that you could solve your problem! If you think my answer helped you may upvote it and possibly accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing `let ref = db.collection('post').doc(this.$route.params.id)` you get a [`DocumentReference`](http://ps://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) as detailed in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc).

Then by doing `get()` on this `DocumentReference` you get a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), as detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get), and not a `QuerySnapshot`.

So you should get the doc data via the `data()` method (or the `get(<field>)` to get a specific field) and not by doing `snapshot.forEach(doc => {})` which should be used on a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#forEach).

So, in other words, do as follows:

```
let ref = db.collection('post').doc(this.$route.params.id)
ref.get()
.then(snapshot => {  //DocSnapshot
      if (snapshot.exists) {
          let post = snapshot.data()
      } else {
          // snapshot.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
      }  
})
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help but doesn't work for me, I've updated my question above with what i get